# Swift metatype and .self

Tags: swift

I have no idea what is meta type and .self (instance?) and how it's useful in Swift that I have not come across any other languages. Layman term will help.

```
A.Type
A.self
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the *Metatype Type* section in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html?

Comment: Probably I need to know how it being use, any tutorials for playground example?